# Several jumbotron's with different background colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to put on page several jumbotron's (bootstrap 3) with different background colors.
Help me, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see here, just add a class to overide the default jumbotron background color :

**Bootply :** http://bootply.com/112356

**HTML :**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron other-color">
  <h1>Hello, people!</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.other-color{
    background: green
  }
```